# GAE configuration & Billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcloud

Google App Engine: Few weeks back I have developed an RoR application in GAE with aditional resources as CloudSQL and Storage Bucket.

Our application is very simple CMS site. Here the app size details, 
Application size not more than - 200Mb.
Storage - 90MB
SQL - 100MB

I have chosen free trail so I got 300$ as Credit limit. Since its a Ruby we can't choose standard env so  we used Flex. We have developed this site as UAT environment. So obviously we don't have much traffic appx not more than 50 vists per day. But within 20 days all my Credit gone.

Also I have used lowest CPU, min max instance count and SQL Storage size.

So why its charging more? 
Is this normal?
Is there a different billing metrics for free and paid?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud has charges on many ends so it is hard to say what was responsible - you can check

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails/history?project=yorprojectname what exactly caused the cost on the GAE end

On Cloud SQL, there is also a quite complex charge model, but basically you will be charged for running instances, see:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#2nd-gen-instance-pricing

You can check your billing history with GAE / Cloud SQL combined under

https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/0090BB-BB0B17-DB02CE/history?project=yorprojectname

That way you should be able to find out what caused the cost and act accordingly to prevent  / optimize

Comment: To make the links in GeraldDC's post useful, one needs to choose the name of the project of interest from the "Select a project" drop-down menu top-left of the developers' console page.